# Eclipse CDT across class analysis

Tags: c, parsing, eclipse-cdt, static-analysis

The [AssignmentToItselfChecker.java](https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/blob/main/codan/org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers/src/org/eclipse/cdt/codan/internal/checkers/AssignmentToItselfChecker.java) captures Self assignments within the same translation unit. But if the value propagates through header and the same assignment is done, it won't capture, which is quite as expected. I'm running this as a standalone Parser [link](https://github.com/VenoVeno/CDT-Failed-Demo/blob/main/SampleParser.java).

#### Sample C Snippet Code:

##### A.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "A.h"

int main() {
    int number1 = 100;
    number1 = callMe(number1); // Checker fails to capture, as callMe() is in another Translation Unit

    int number2 = 100;
    number2 = number2; // Checker will report issue here.
}
```

##### A.h:

```
int callMe(int number) {
    return number;
}
```

Github Source : [repo](https://github.com/VenoVeno/CDT-Failed-Demo/tree/main)

Is there any working solution to achieve this using Taint Analysis or lookup in other translation unit? Any working solution without IDE (Standalone) is fine. May be i'm missing something that's already available. Correct me if i'm wrong anywhere.

CDT Version : 11.0

Java Version : Open JDK 17

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [You are running an Eclipse CDT version that is more than 5 years behind](https://github.com/VenoVeno/CDT-Failed-Demo/blob/main/lib/org.eclipse.cdt.core_6.2.0.201612061315.jar). If there is something missing in CDT, consider to contribute what is missing.

Comment: @howlger Please have a check now for the latest JAR.  There is a provisioning to add (https://github.com/VenoVeno/CDT-Failed-Demo/blob/main/SampleParser.java#L29). But the Parser is not including the path. I'm missing something. I don't know what it is.

Comment: The `c` tag should probably not be used here as the question really doesn't have anything whatsoever to do with C (even though the input example text is arguably C code).